# css is not showing background cover on the web page

Tags: html, css

I want to fix an image as a background cover.

This is my css file:

```
.venue-end-banner{
    background-image:url('../images/partner-testimonial-banner.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

and this html code

```
<div class="venue-end-banner">

  </div>
```

but it's not showing anything. Please someone help me. Thanks

Comment: Inspect it and check if the element have height or add padding-bottom: some value.

Comment: we can not help you with so little information .. Is your css file loaded?

the URL of your image is the right one?

Comment: yes css is loaded and url is correct one

Comment: Try to put some content inside that div, like a <p></p>. If you have it empty, you won't see any background image

Comment: height is not working
and background-size:cover is not been accepted in the inspect element

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a height to the venue-end-banner element. Without any content, the browser assumes a height of zero.

```
.venue-end-banner{
  background-image:url('../images/partner-testimonial-banner.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  height:200px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no content in the `div`, therefore the height of the block is equal to 0. Just add some content to your `div` or edit your CSS as following:

```css
.venue-end-banner {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="venue-end-banner"></div>
```

Also, make sure, the image URL is correct and *partner-testimonial-banner.jpg* file has been loaded succefuly.

Comment: but but this is making the image to occupy the given height and width 
it is still not showing the cover

Comment: @juhi , are you sure? If you run the snippet from my post, then you will see background image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok your problem is because your div is empty, so height is 0.

You need to add this value to your div css.

Like :

```
min-height : 100px;
```

Comment: Width is not zero if a block element is empty. Just the height